# Over-fitting issue in a classification problem (unbalanced data)

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, classification, r, decision-trees

I am working on a rare event (unbalanced target variable) classification problem using decision trees. My dataset comprises of 95% non-event and 5% minority (events) class.

I used decision tree over logistic regression because I had many categorical variables comparing to continuous variables. I get a  good performance for training data with the decision tree C5.0. However I get poor results for the new data. I use the confusion matrix as a measure of performance. Training model is over-fitting.

I did pruning to reduce the over-fitting caused by the decision tree.  I used the following code to build the model

```
Classifi_C5.0 <- C5.0(TARGET ~., , data = training_data_SMOTED, trails = 500,
                      control = C5.0Control(minCases = mincases_count,
                                            noGlobalPruning = FALSE))
```

I balanced the minority and majority class using the following code:

```
training_data_SMOTED <- SMOTE(TARGET ~ ., training_data,
                              perc.over = 100, k = 5, perc.under = 200)
```

Any sort of advice will be helpful.

Comment: You can try [cross-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)) for fitting your hyper-parameters. It might not help that much in your case.

Comment: When you say good performance for training data, what do you mean?Predicting the majority class all the time  will get you 95% accuracy. But you may have a cost matrix which makes this  an unattractive choice  ?

Comment: @image_doctor, For training data. i get close to 75% accuracy for both majority class and minortiy class. However when i bring in some new data to test for the performance, there it is not giving good results. I get accuracy close to 40% in the new data. Simply put, my model is not robust or it is over-fitting.

Comment: @mic , thanks for the suggestion. I tried k fold cross validation for rpart. However i dont know how to use the same in C5.0 algorithm in R.

Comment: @image_doctor, what you are referring as cost matrix? is that a technique ?

Comment: @Arun It's a way of expressing the different values placed on correctly and incorrectly classifying instances of your data. Perhaps misclassifying the minority class has a great cost, perhaps it doesn't , using a cost matrix accounts for this.

Comment: @image_doctor, thanks for the explanation. Could you please advice me whether cost matrix possible in random forest? I use R. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I'm working on a similar classification problem using Quinlans `C5.0` and in my experience there are couple of tweaks inside that might help you.

- First, I believe using such big number (trials=500) for boosting is
  affecting the overfitting, since the model will repeatedly try and
  improve on the misclassified instances in every iteration. Try using
  a smaller boosting size, or even turning it off - it might help with
  the overfitting problem.
- There are a couple of other parameters you might find useful. The minimal leaf size (`minCases` in `C5.0Control()` is something to you want to keep as big as possible when avoiding overfitting issues.
- Another one is the confidence factor (`CF`) which lets you control
  the severity of pruning of the tree, meaning lower factor levels will likely prune away the leaves which overspecify the classification.
- Finally, you might try using the `fuzzyThreshold` control option which lets you 'soften' sharp thresholds with an inbetween grey area.

These are all very well documented in the [`C5.0`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/C50/C50.pdf) vignette as well as on the [informal tutorial page](https://www.rulequest.com/see5-unix.html).

Hope this helps you a bit.